# Can't Click an Object in Selenium in Some Google Image Search Results

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm trying to pull urls of images from Google Image Search results. As you know from using Google Image Search you click on a small photo in the grid to get a bigger image to pop down below it. This is where my Selenium Chrome Webdriver stops.
I've tried the .click() command and the .send_keys(Keys.RETURN) command. I've also tried the .send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN) command to try to open it in a new tab.
There are four different elements under the search result of the small image I want to click on in order to get at the full image. Three of the elements return a
"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element"
The X-Path in the code below doesn't give that error but it doesn't do anything. Terminal just goes back to the $ prompt.
I can't seem to get the photo and buttons below to pop down for anything. When I tell Selenium to do things to elements in the menu I can't get to open it says the element is not visible.
I don't want to use their API because I need more images than their API limits.

Here's the code. I'm thinking of another option below this code.

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

list3 = ["rags and scraps"]


#Setup The Automated Browser (brew install chromedriver)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=/user/anthonycelio/selgoog/chrome_driver') #Path to your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.27/bin/chromedriver')#, chrome_options=options) #Type 'brew list chromedriver' to find path

driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=cats+and+dogs&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1599&bih=726&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI56_7isXSAhXC4iYKHcbZCLEQ_AUIBigB#q=cats+and+dogs&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbs=sur:fc&*")

for i in list3:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="lst-ib"]""").clear()
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="lst-ib"]""")
    inputElement.send_keys(list3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="_fZl"]""").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="rg_s"]/div[1]/a""").click()
```

This might be a different option to store the url of the image if Google has made their images unclickable by Selenium: One of the elements has the link in it if you copy the outerHTML. The problem is they have stuffed code into the link. I wonder if it can be removed with any consistency.

```
<a href="/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fa%2Fab%2FFrank_G._Carpenter%2C_Salvaging_scraps_on_the_streets_of_Paris.jpg&amp;imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcommons.wikimedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFile%3AFrank_G._Carpenter%2C_Salvaging_scraps_on_the_streets_of_Paris.jpg&amp;docid=iNT670hfj_m0nM&amp;tbnid=ziffAZE9s2oycM%3A&amp;vet=1&amp;w=7290&amp;h=5614&amp;safe=off&amp;bih=705&amp;biw=1050&amp;q=rags%20and%20scraps&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjkhr_MqMXSAhUFfiYKHQ5JBpkQMwgaKAAwAA&amp;iact=mrc&amp;uact=8" jsaction="fire.ivg_o;mouseover:str.hmov;mouseout:str.hmou" class="rg_l" rel="noopener" style="background: rgb(120, 117, 101); width: 188px; height: 161px; left: 0px;"><img class="rg_ic rg_i" data-sz="f" name="ziffAZE9s2oycM:" alt="Image result for rags and scraps" jsaction="load:str.tbn" onload="google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" style="width: 209px; height: 161px; margin-left: -10px; margin-right: -11px; margin-top: 0px;"><div class="_aOd rg_ilm"><div class="rg_ilmbg"><span class="rg_ilmn"> 7290&nbsp;×&nbsp;5614 - commons.wikimedia.org </span></div></div></a>

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Frank_G._Carpenter,_Salvaging_scraps_on_the_streets_of_Paris.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option would be the second thing you mentioned. You can extract the `href` value, then run it through `urllib`'s `unquote` function. When you are on the image results page:

```
import urllib

images = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('rg_l')
for image in images:
    href = image.get_attribute('href')
    if '?imgurl=' in href:  # Do this because often times the last result will not be an actual image
        image_url_raw = href.split('?imgurl=')[1].split('&imgrefurl=')[0]
        image_url = urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote(image_url_raw))
```

If  you are on Python3, you need to use `urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.unquote(image_url_raw))` instead

Comment: Using the same principle he can also just driver.get the URL.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Sorry for the ameture question but how could I grab just the first 20?

Comment: @Ant change `for image in images` to `for image in images[:20]`

Comment: I'm still marveling that this is possible. So the second from the last line in my code above that has the href link to the photo is always changed by Google in that specific way and urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.unquote()) knows what to do with it because it is a common process? Why is the unquote applied twice?